# How to display geotagged photos in leaflet

Tags: leaflet, clustering, geolocation, photos

There is awsome plugin of displaying geotagged photos in leaflet 
[Photos on leaflet](http://blog.thematicmapping.org/2014/08/showing-geotagged-photos-on-leaflet-map.html)

I used the picasa photos implimentation
when I implemented the plugin for  my picasa public album photos link in this format
https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/**MY-USER-ID**/albumid/**MY-ALBUM-ID**?alt=json-in-script

my example failed even my link work perfectly and broadcast Json data

Can you show me how to use that plug in?

Comment: The plugin looks fine, so there is a high chance the issue is in your implementation. Please could you share your code in your question? Again, if you could reproduce your issue in Plunker or JSFiddle, that would make debugging easier. You can use the user ID from the blog if you do not want to share yours. By the way, when your questions are really programming oriented, and not so much on GIS themselves, you may receive quicker help on Stack Overflow.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/7mbi66G7grJ1rnfudzcw?p=preview

Comment: Hi I think the problem is in my link of picasa photo album here the working code of theire example and my picasa album link commented http://plnkr.co/edit/7mbi66G7grJ1rnfudzcw?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out Picasa has an extra privacy parameter on location data of photos that are going to be shared as public.

The "Show photo locations to viewers of this album" parameter must be checked for geotags to be sent with the photos metadata, even if those photos are already publicly shared.

See also OP's answer below.

---

Unfortunately it looks like your photos miss geographic coordinates data (no geotag).

In Picasaweb, open your photo and then click on the "full details page" link on the far right menu (for left-to-right languages). There should be `Latitude` and `Longitude` data. Like for example in photos from Bjørn's album (author of Leaflet.photo plugin): https://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/nfgH9Rj2jbZlllxLLM0aDNMTjNZETYmyPJy0liipFm0?full-exif=true

You can also inspect the JSONP response by simply typing your URL (`https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/MY-USER-ID/albumid/MY-ALBUM-ID?alt=json-in-script`) in the browser location bar: you need `['georss$where']['gml$Point']['gml$pos']['$t']` attributes available for the plugin to be able to determine the location of your photos.

Comment: Well, I see date, size, resolution, and other camera-related data, but no "Latitude" nor "Longitude"? Which data is supposed to carry the coordinates information in the link you provided?

Comment: When I am logged in picasa it shows me the longitude & latitude data when I am logged out there are no data of geolocalisation?

Comment: mm interesting! Maybe you have some privacy parameters that hide this data from public. I did not think we would have that fine-grained control! Look in your Picasa account if you can make this data public as well, at least for these photos.

Comment: Maybe this post can help you: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/picasa/BVk0u5b1rNY

Answer (score 0):

Now it works; you must not only make the album public but you have to check **Show photo locations to viewers of this album** even the photo is geolocated.if not the image stay ungeolocated

Comment: I am glad I could help! Thank you for the accepted answer. I will edit it to reflect your finding as well.

Comment: I want the same effect but with geotagged photos locally with no hosting No connexion .

Comment: This should work in a very similar way, the only difficulty might be having offline tiles. Feel free to open a new question to get some help.

Answer (score 0):

Picassa now is no more active it is replaced by google photos but the plug in of leaflet photos is still working only the album must be public and share Log Lat (exif data) mmust be active .

1) For making the album public https://www.svenbluege.de/picasa/v1.1/

2) For sharing  Log lat of photos location see here 
https://support.google.com/plus/answer/6008918?hl=en

Comment: For making the album public https://www.svenbluege.de/picasa/v1.1/ is not working since  02/09/2017 Google has made its promisse true. It is not longer possible to change album properties through the API. That means you can't change any of the albums  .How can we make an album public to use Photos on leaflet?

Comment: I found a solution, I build a new album as permission of public via the old software picasa and then put in that album what I want of photos via google photos or  picasa